# uninitialized constant User::PhotoUploader

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, minimagick

Iam trying to use mini_magick,but after following the git guide i still recieve uninitialized constant. i have another project working just fine using the same syntax.. however must be missing something ..

photo_uploader.rb

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

   def default_url
    "photo.jpg"
   end

  #right orientation
  def right_orientation
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.auto_orient
      img
    end
  end

   def filename
     "photo.jpg" if original_filename
   end
end
```

user.rb

```
require 'bcrypt'
require 'carrierwave'
require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :pakars
    has_many :courses

    scoped_search on: [:name1, :name2]
    mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
    attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation

    def self.authenticate(email, pass)
      u=where("email =?", email).first
      return nil if u.nil?
      return u if BCrypt::Password.new(u.hashed_password) == pass
      nil
    end
    def password=(pass)
      self.hashed_password = BCrypt::Password.create(pass)
    end


end
```

Here is the error

```
uninitialized constant User::PhotoUploader

Rails.root: C:/Users/User/Desktop/Ruby_training/Project/Pakar_my
```

and yes i already installed the gems

Gemfile

```
#carrier wave
gem 'carrierwave'
#mini_magick
gem 'mini_magick' , '3.7.0'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to add `carrierwave` to your `application.rb` file like this:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

require 'carrierwave'

if defined?(Bundler)
  # Bundler stuff
end
```

Try this may be it's work for you

> Or sometime just restart rails server and after it everything worked
>   fine. :)